# How can I set up a 3 Computer fileserver system?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, raspberry-pi, raspbian, file-server

My parents separated, and now I have two computers at different houses.

When working with various files I would really love to be able to just walk over and continue at the other place, meaning that I'd need some kind of file server setup that copies the files from one system to the other, on a 30min basis.
The problem is that the computers will **not be active at the same time**, thus I'd need some kind of middle server that handles the 'waiting' files whilst one or both are off, and when one computer turns on it downloads the files immediately.

For money-saving purposes I was thinking of a raspberry Pi3 as the middle-server.
It will be on 24/7, always ready to recive files and transfer them to the next computer asking for them. After transfered succesfully it will be removed from the pi3's memory.

**Note: I want the folder structure to be preserved. (Not changed.)**

The setup will be as follows:
**Windows PC 1 -> Pi3 -> Windows PC 2**, and vice versa.

Do any of you have any ideas how can I accomplish this, or do you have any better/cheaper ideas? (If any instructions are given, please remember that I have no previous experiences with Raspbian, nor any complex programming. And be kind. Thanks!)

Comment: Why not just an external Hard Drive or USB Stick?

Comment: Well, That is my backup plan. However I'd prefer not having to copy stuff everytime I walk over, and having to wait for it to finish. Also I like to do stuff in the most complicated of ways ;)

Answer (score 2):

What happen with Onedrive, ownCloud, Dropbox, Google Drive, Mega ... ?
You use it as if it were another folder on your system. It synchronizes with the cloud. From another pc you can install it or access via web. Very easy.

Comment: Well, that _is_ one option. However the files are quite large and I'd soon run out of space, and I also do not trust 3'd party fileserver-stuff enough for that. I like to make my own solutions, not needing to depend very much on others. Less points of possible failures. Also, no harm meant, but I asked this on superuser for a reason; I like to make _advanced_ solutions, and I feel like this is the best working solution for me at the time. However I really appreciate your response, thanks!